# Sheets Query, when order by asc shows empty

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have this query:

=QUERY($D:$J,"select D,"&L4&" where E<0.75 order by E desc")

Works fine, just fine

but if instead of desc I use asc

=QUERY($D:$J,"select D,"&L4&" where E<0.75 order by E asc")

Brings no value, just the headers. I'd expect the same data in reversed order but nothing instead

Comment: Perhaps there are a bunch of empty cells and you are seeing those first.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not seeing those "first", there is nothing being shown. It turns out that you were right. I changed the range to the specific range and it works. I'll have to indirect the range to adapt to different cases though.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Query considers all empty existing cells within the range as part of the results, so by selecting the whole columns all the empty ranges are also part of the select results and by ordering ascending, all empty cells go first with the apparent empty return.
The way to solve this is to indicate a fixed range matching the actual table or adding the condition to ignore blanks by adding the condition such as Col>=0 if numbers or Col IS NOT NULL.